# Concat two properties injected from a file.properties

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Well basically what I need to achieve is to concat properties parsed from the conf/file.properties file in my endpoint's uri. Something like:

```
<endpoint name="TestEndpoint">
    <address uri="{$FILE:host}:{$FILE:port}/rest/of/url"/>
</endpoint>
```

However all the options I've tried failed. Is it even possible to achieve something like that?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

The injecting parameters feature from **file.properties** ships with WSO2EI 6.6.0, and for endpoints it is well described here: [Supported Endpoint parameters](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Injecting+Parameters+using+Configuration+Files#InjectingParametersusingConfigurationFiles-Endpointparameters) This feature can't concat this, as you want. Only the **RecipientList Endpoint** has the hostname and port, but it is nasty workaround.

In some similar way, you can use template sequence to concat address. And as source of hostname and port you use Local Registry Entries or Configuration registry. It also depends of what version of wso2esb/ei you use.

Answer (score -1):

If you need an address endpoint you can set the "To" Header with a concatenation of two values and then call the default endpoint. I reckon this should work for the $file as well.

Address:

```
<header expression="concat($file:x, ':', $file:y)" name="To" scope="default" />
    <call>
        <endpoint>
            <default />
        </endpoint>
    </call>
```

Comment: It will won't work. You will get error: `Evaluation of the XPath expression concat($file:x, ':', $file:y) resulted in an error org.jaxen.UnresolvableException: Variable x`. Even you use proper naming `$FILE` it don't work like that.

Comment: Unfortunate, hoped they would keep it consistent, sorry for the misinformation then!

Comment: Perhaps alternatively if you put the values into properties first that might work?

Comment: I tried putting it into properties however didn't succeed.